# Theoretically(!) is it possible to write analog signal (sound) to HDD, like on magnet tape?

Tags: hard-drive, analog

I mean, with hardware modifications of HDD, for example, by connecting directly to heads to record signal, and then play it back.

Comment: FYI the HDD always records an analog signal.  The digital information is modulated, typically a variation on frequency modulation.  Rather than try to write "ones" and "zeros", the magnetic particles are magnetized so that a flux reversal denotes a bit state transition, e.g. 1->0 or 0->1.

Comment: Super User focuses on real world problems rather than theoretical ones, and this isn't about computer hardware or software as defined for the site, so it's probably off-topic.  But it's an interesting question.   Have you looked at how sound was encoded on tape?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With sufficient hardware modifications: Why not.

As an alternative to sufficient modification you could also buy your own device starting from just electronics without ever touching a HDD. It is just how you define *sufficient modifications*

Consider that modern drive spins at speeds like 5400 or 7200 RPM; that is 90 or 120 rounds per second. So you could only record 1/90 <sup>th</sup> or 1/120 <sup>th</sup> second per track. And then you need to stop recording to reposition the head.

So yes, it is possible. But not practical.

Comment: If you were going down this route you could use just one spiral track so wouldn't need to reposition the head. Still not practical though:)

Comment: Agreed. But one would need to replace the head actuators. I think those are designed to only move in steps of one track. Then again: *sufficient modifications* :)

Comment: with sufficient modifications you could probably even make it *actually play it back* :-)

Comment: @Hennes - stepper motors for the heads were obsolete decades ago.  A voice coil actuator could be made to do a spiral track.

Comment: I guess I am showing my age. Soon I will no longer be able to tell 'when we had a 5 **MB** drive with a broken sector 0 we rewired the head so head/sector 0 was on a different platter" (or able to tell but with none left to understand it).

Answer (score 2):

This is actually how freeze-frame in live sports broadcasts was first done in the 60s, [they had a specialized hard drive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ampex#HS-100_.26_HS-200_.22slo-mo.22_disc_recorder) that would record the analog video frames to the platter, one frame per rovolution, and they'd change which frame was being played back by moving the heads in/out.